# RTSP stream to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rtsp, rtsp-client, wpf-mediakit

I have a device with an RTSP stream that I can consume using the VLC media player. When connected, VLC says the stream says this about the current media info/codec:

Type: Video
Codec: Motion JPEG Video (MJPG)
Resolution: 352x240
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV full scale

I have attempted to use the WPF MediaKit ( https://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/ ) but it does not like the protocol. The error it returns is 'The specified protocol is unknown.'

What other ways are there to consume this stream and display it in a WPF app?

Comment: I have looked at https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/ , but having to have VLC installed is not an option for code we plan to distribute.

Comment: WPF MediaKit - the problem is in the codecs. Other user has reported a partial success: https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VLC ActiveX control. In order to display the control in a WPF application you will have to use WinForms interop. The VLC Active X control is a COM component and so can be embedded in a WinForms control